# How to hide the browser address bar with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it possible to hide the user's address bar in the browser?  If so, how would I go about it?

Comment: Did you mean for new window like pop-up window?

Comment: you can only do that on pop-up window.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can hide the address bar on a user's current window but you can create a pop up that has the address bar hidden:

```
var popup = window.open("http://someurl", "myPopup", 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=120,height=120')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [modeless](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Javascript-Objects/ShowModelessDialogwindowshowModelessDialog.htm) window (IE), but you cannot hijack the browser's current page.

FF does not support this as it took them 3 years to implement the showModalDiaglog, which was  more secure than IE's implementation.

Your option is to:

- Open a new window, hiding the address bar, but it would still be available
- Create an absolutely positioned element w/in the current page that contains an iframe
- Create your own browser and add that feature

Answer (score 1):

Can't do it reliably and it's not a good idea, even for popups, I think currently, IE is the only one that will hide it. Otherwise the user doesn't know where the popup is from. Think about the facebook login popup. How am I supposed to be confident that I'm not entering my password into a malicious website?